# Multiple jQuery functions not working properly in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, function, codeigniter, calendar

I included a file named functions.php in my codeigniter view page the fist function in the page was working others are not. Here is my script:

```js
function getCalendar(target_div, year, month) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'functions.php',
        data: 'func=getCalender&year=' + year + '&month=' + month,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#' + target_div).html(html);
        }
    });
}

function getEvents(date) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'functions.php',
        data: 'func=getEvents&date=' + date,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#event_list').html(html);
            $('#event_add').slideUp('slow');
            $('#event_list').slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date_cell').mouseenter(function() {
        date = $(this).attr('date');
        $(".date_popup_wrap").fadeOut();
        $("#date_popup_" + date).fadeIn();
    });
    $('.date_cell').mouseleave(function() {
        $(".date_popup_wrap").fadeOut();
    });
    $('.month_dropdown').on('change', function() {
        getCalendar('calendar_div', $('.year_dropdown').val(), $('.month_dropdown').val());
    });
    $('.year_dropdown').on('change', function() {
        getCalendar('calendar_div', $('.year_dropdown').val(), $('.month_dropdown').val());
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#event_list').slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

so any one pls help me to make it work properly

Comment: You need to explain a bit more about the problem and what not working. What is your expectation for the code to do?

Comment: Where are you calling these functions? Why are you not wrapping these functions in a js file?

Comment: i trying to display the database value to a calendar format andit is working but when clicking the view event link the function get_evemt need to work but it is not working

Comment: <?php include_once('functions.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo  base_url('resource/css/styles.css'); ?>" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="calendar_div">
        <?php echo getCalender(); ?>
    </div>

</body>

</html>

Comment: this is my index.php file

Comment: both index.php and functions.php files are in the same view page

Comment: is my question clear

Comment: any one knows the answer pls hlp

Comment: any one knows the answer